# Which query works in both SQL Server and Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am searching for a `SELECT` query that works in both SQL Server and Oracle. It does not matter what it selects or what the result is, but it cannot depend on the database contents.

This sounds like a simple thing to do, but I cannot come up with an example.

First I thought of `SELECT 0`, but Oracle needs `FROM dual` which SQL Server does not support. Then I tried `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, but Oracle does not have those...

**Edit:** this question arose trying to check whether some SQL Server linked servers are reachable. But I think it is very interesting by itself.

Comment: I don't think there is one, unless you define a `dual` table in SQL Server, unless there is some arcane system table that has the same name in both databases.

Comment: We must know what it selects or the results are, so that we may help you formulate a query with only standard sql

Comment: Perhaps `select * from (values(1))`?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis "It does not matter what it selects or what the result is": any working query will do!

Comment: @jarlh That's not valid in either database.

Comment: Too bad, plain ANSI SQL...

Comment: Would such a query have any practical point, though? Is this intended as a generic way of testing whether the server is reachable, or something? `RETURN;` should be a legal no-op in both T-SQL and PL/SQL (but don't quote me on the latter, you may need `BEGIN`/`END` as well).

Comment: I think he's looking for a portable way to create a table-less result set.  Oracle uses `DUAL`, DB2 uses `SYSDUMMY`, other engines use the `VALUES` keyword, still other ones can have a `SELECT` without a `FROM table`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On rextester, the following works for both [SQL Server](http://rextester.com/HIJD38396) and [Oracle](http://rextester.com/WCPQCZ19130):

```
select count(*)
from sys.all_objects;
```

There may be a handful of other sys tables that this would work for.

EDIT:

I'm going to echo Jeroen's comment.  If you want the same *result* as well, then add a clause that filters out all rows:

```
select count(*) as always_zero
from sys.all_objects
where 1 = 0;
```

Comment: You've been faster than me ;)

Comment: `SELECT 'My result set',1,2,3 FROM ( select count(*) DUMMY from sys.all_objects ) DUMMY`

Comment: Even though "it doesn't matter what the result is", adding `where 1 = 0` would make the result predictable (and allow at least the SQL Server optimizer to elide access to the table entirely).

Comment: Works great for SQL Server 2008+!

Comment: Then `SELECT 0 FROM sys.all_objects WHERE 1 = 0` is easiest.